# How to add file size

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to make a script in linux which sums all the file sizes from a directory into a variable. Until now I have managed to write the code to open and see what is inside a directory although I get the following error when I try to compile it with `gcc -o` command:

```
Error: admin1@admin1-virtual-machine:~$ gcc -o dir Dir.c
/tmp/ccuNE2Q3.o: In function `main':
Dir.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `prinf'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The code so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    struct stat buf;
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dr;

    if (argv[1]==NULL) {
        printf("Utilizare:    %s director\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    stat (argv[1], &buf);

    if (!S_ISDIR(buf.st_mode)) {
        perror(argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    dr = opendir(argv[1]);
    while(entry=readdir(dr)) {
        prinf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider reading what compiler actually says to you as being able to read and understand it is very important and makes finding a solution way easier.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the `prinf` to `printf`?